# Is there a way to correctly concatenate two arbitrary XPath expressions to result in a new valid XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking for a way to concatenate two arbitrary, valid XPath expressions to build a new XPath expression.

Effectively I'd like to apply the second XPath expression on the result of the first XPath expression.

For example, take this XML:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz />
  </bar>
<foo>
```

The XPath expression `/foo` would obviously return the root element, while `/bar` would return nothing. But `/bar` applied to the result of `/foo` should return the `<bar>`element.

Now the naive implementation would be to just use String concatenation to build `/foo/bar` and evaluate that to get `<bar>`. This works in this specific case.

Now my question is: is it always that simple? Are there any types of XPath expressions where this won't result in a valid expression or would lead to unexpected results?

It isn't much of a problem if some obscure XPath expressions can't be validated that way, but I'd like the common ones to work.

If there are problems: Is there any kind of concatenation that works in more situations?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for detailed discussion and many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0** the `/` operator requires that its operand to the left is of type that selects a nodeset and its operand to the right is a relative XPath expression -- also is of type selecting a nodeset.

Therefore, any `expr1` that evaluates to a simple value (number, string, boolean) cannot be used to the left of `/`. This is exactly true for the right-hand-side argument of `/`.

**Examples** of invalid XPath 1.0 expressions:

```
string(/foo)/bar

count(//foo)/bar

(/foo/baz = 3)/bar

/foo/count(bar)
```

**In XPath 2.0** it is still required that in `expr1/expr2` `expr1` must evaluate to a node-set. However, `expr2` can be a function call. Thus the following are valid and have meaningful results:

`/foo/bar/string-length(.)`    (: a sequence of integers that are the string lengths of every `/foo/bar` node :)

`/foo/bar/name(.)`    (: a sequence of strings that are the names of every `/foo/bar` node :)

`foo/bar/count(node())`  (: a sequence of integers that are the number of children nodes of every `/foo/bar` node :)

**There are other connectors that may be used** to combine two expressions to produce a third one:

In both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0:

The **union** operator:

```
expr1 | expr2
```

The **comparison** operators:

```
expr1 = expr2
expr1 >= expr2
expr1 < expr2
expr1 <= expr2
expr1 != expr2
```

The **boolean** operators and the `not()` function:

```
not(expr1)

expr1 and expr2

expr1 or expr2
```

**In XPath 2.0**:

the operators `except`, `intersect` `union`

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I was only thinking of expressions that select node sets (because those are most important to me), so I missed a big chunk!

Comment: @Joachim-Sauer: Glad my answer was useful. Consider accepting it? :)